# XML parsing _ dealing with an exception ... basic PHP problem

Tags: php, xml, extract

I have written a perfectly working XML parser using PHP...
using,

> $xml = simplexml_load_file($newfile);

Now, The newfile was a pointer to an xml file that has over 20000 lines.
The problem was, the system ( an android) started generating tags called

> <  none  >

... when no value existed...
BUT,  there is NO <  /none  > tag  ... There are multiple < none > values !!
It seems like
a) Either instruct Android not to do this ! - TRIED, but it can't be controlled .. OS deals with it.

b) or, Create a PHP loophole to prevent this error !

I need help. How do I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [< none > tags - XML parsing using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505690/none-tags-xml-parsing-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there no end tag - xml is not valid. If there only issue with *none* tag you can try ignore it in your parser. Or even try remove *none* tags with php "find and replace" functions like preg_replace before dealing with parser

Comment: I need to oautomate this... Pl let me know how to get rid of this problem ... what's preg-replace ?