# < none > tags - XML parsing using PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

When I am parsing an XML file, there are some `<none>` tags that the system automatically generates for various fields...  BUT, There are no `</none>` tags . 
So, my XML parser gives errors and is not parsing the ENTIRE file.

How do I get rid of this error?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($newfile3);
```

`<none>` is not a tag ... So, I just want to ignore this  or replace with something else like "none" ...

Comment: If you fix your invalid XML, then you won't have to come up with a hack to parse invalid XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newfile3 = str_replace('<none>', '&lt;none&gt;', $newfile3);
```

basically replace the bad 'tag' with the two metacharacters encoded into entities.

Comment: I am still getting the same error... I checked the newfile3 and it still has the <  none  > tags ...

Comment: You're typing it in here with space before/after the brackets `<[space]none`. If that's really there in the xml , you have to enter an exact match into the str_replace call.

Comment: No, That's not there ! The editor in this website DOES NOT display  anything if I type in NONE within the tags !!

Comment: Issue resolved... I added fwrite after getting $strings with str_replace and loaded the new file. Thanks a lot Mark !

Comment: Oh, and if you want to embed a code block within some regular text, like for displaying an HTML tag, you can enclose the tag within backticks ( ` ), and you'll get `<none>`

Answer (score 0):

Zac, you should load the file first, then use the code from Marc B

```
$string = str_replace('<none>', 'your_replacement', file_get_contents($newfile3));
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Again the error is " Opening and ending tag mismatch: none " ... I don't know how to solve this ! maybe does it not read <none> as a string ??!

Comment: Then maybe you should post your file (pastebin.com is a perfect spot) so we can take a look ...

Comment: Looking at your other question related to this problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5495543/209012) I guess Marc is right; there are space between `<` and `none` so take my code and enter what needs to be replace; `< none >` instead of `<none>`

Comment: No, That's not there ! The editor in this website DOES NOT display anything if I type in NONE within the tags !!Hence the added space .. I tried fwrite ($fp,$string) and then used simplexml_load_file($newfile3) and IT almost workied... but other problems occur, like improper write... The last line was written improperly... I have no idea how this could happen !